# Need to install visual studio and sql server on macbook pro

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, macbook-pro, boot-camp

I am a developer, I just got a macbook pro and I need to be able to use IIS, Visual Studio and SQL Server like I did on my old windows notebook. I understand that I need to get windows first but I am totally new to mac and I am confused about the difference between installing parallels windows or using the bootcamp to install windows. Are both the same or different things? What do I need to do to be able to install them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am sorry for your purchase ;) Out of curiosity why buy a Mac as a developer, trying to branch out?

Comment: Actually I didn't buy it, it was a gift :)

Comment: One is a virtual machine one isn't

Answer (score 4):

Bootcamp (free from Apple) gives you the ability to boot your system into Windows, which is installed on a separate disk partition from OS X. OS X functions are not available while Windows is running.

Parallels ($), VMWare Fusion ($), and VirtualBox (free) are virtual machine managers, which allow you to create a Windows (or other O/S) system that runs within a program window in OS X. These will slow your system down because it is doing the processing for Windows and OS X at the same time.

For both of these solutions, you need a Windows license.

If you don't want to buy Windows and are super adventurous, you could try installing CrossOver ($), which allows you to install some windows software so it runs directly on OS X (that is, masquerading as a native OS X program), but Visual Studio is known to be flaky in that environment, so I advise against this. Masochists may feel free to ignore my advice.

Comment: I have no problem buying a windows licence, I just need to know which to buy, windows or parallels windows. How can I decide which is better, you mentioned that with parallels the system will slow down, does this mean I should go with bootcamp or there are other factors?

Comment: Crossover/Wine will not run Visual studio.  I would highly recommend bootcamp.  You are running Windows natively, not in a virtual machine.  When compiling applications, you want as much horsepower as the machine can give.  You shouldnt have issues running a VM in Parallels, but why take a risk?

Comment: I'm sorry I am still confused about something here, you mentioned that parallels is a virtual machine manager, this means that if I decided to go with it then I'll need to buy parallels and then buy a windows licence to install it with parallels?

Comment: If I may answer for Br.Bill, yes, you would need a Parallels license and a Windows license in order to go that route.  The advantage of Parallels, VMware Fusion, etc, is that they can run other operating systems, if you want. If it's just Windows you're after, Bootcamp is the cheaper and better-performing option.

Comment: @To sum it up, Bootcamp is essentially dual booting. The others are virtual machines.

Comment: @AthomSfere does hyper-v support OSX got this crazy idea where he boots to a OS X virtual machine lol

Comment: @Ramhound I do not believe it does, but if I were you I would post that as a question :) I believe OS X requires certain interactivity with Apple's special UEFI that Hyper-V probably doesn't handle well. I seem to recall VirtualBox had to get Apple Support to allow OS X to boot OSX VMs on OSX...

Comment: @AthomSfere - Like I said it was a crazy idea.  VirtualBox supports the .VHD file extension, and VirtualBox does indeed support OS X, and I believe you might be able still boot to a OS X VHD.  Of course with Bootcamp its not really required, which I might add, is basically how the boot to VHD works in Windows works ( thinking about it I see a lot of similaraties ).

Comment: @PatrickS. regarding the better performing option you mean that with parallels the performance of mac itself will degrade whether or not windows is launched or only when I launch windows? Also what about the specs of the mac itself would it make a difference, mine is 2.3GHz quad-core i7 8GB.

Comment: @Yasmine Only when Windows is launched. In that scenario, you're asking the Mac to run OS X and Windows. In the Bootcamp scenario, it's just one OS at a time. For your 2nd question, in my experience with VMs on PCs, Macs and in VDI, the disk is the limiting factor. CPUs are more than capable these days, it seems to me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, this is on a Microsoft site:

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Parallels-Using-Visual-Studio-on-OSX

It works great with both Parallel, VM-ware or Bootcamp. You can even install it Windows native (multiple partition) on a Mac.

I recommend you to check your workflow first and the choose your solution.
It works great to develop a Mac if you develop for many platforms.